# Onaah with variations of an item

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, transactions, contemporary-halacha, business

There is a Halachic prohibition of Onaah, overcharging the price of a commodity in a market above market price (Choshen Mishpat 227).
Halacha does permit setting a high pricing on new types of goods that you create and sell.
My question is, is it Onaah to charge higher than market rate for a commodity that exists already but is a unique and innovated version of it, for example a new type of iphone with different features, designs, models etc. even though  iPhones already exist.

Comment: Can you source the claims in your first two sentences

Comment: @kirk be to precise (and you might mean that!), that answer refers to items with no market value because of the lack of other sellers, regardless of who invented it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rav Yoel Schwartz writes in [Mammon Kasher (page 90)](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47315&st=&pgnum=90) that one may charge a price higher than market price of an item, given he has a unique variating until everyone else copies him.

Manufacturing it by oneself does not allow one to overcharge for the same product already available on the market. I think you're confusing your second assertion with the prohibition to hoard produce from the market at the end of Choshen Mishpat 231.